# Enyim Memcached client getting cluster cached item count

Tags: c#, .net, memcached, enyim.caching

Is it possible to do this? I think using the `GetValue` method off of stats I can request `curr_items` but that would be from a single server.

Does anyone know of a way through Enyim's memcached client in .NET to retrieve the count of items currently in the cache in the entire cluster?